# Printing individual characters from a string to standard output in ms-dos/assembly x86-16

Tags: dos, x86-16

I am new to x86-16bit programming. I am very stumped by how I call function 2 properly to read characters individually from a string. If anybody has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated. The code below shows my current attempt (one of many).

```
    .model small
    .data
        message db "Hello, DOS Here!", 0dh, 0ah
    .code
    main proc
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax
    L1:
        mov ah, 2
        mov bx, 1
        int 21h
        loop L1

        .EXIT
    main endp
    end main
```

I'm also supposed to use push and pop to be able to print the string in the same method but backwards. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. All I get when it prints is the British pound symbol for a few lines. 
(Dec: 156; Hex: 9C)

Comment: Do you have access to a debugger?  A first step is to understand why it is outputting the character 9C.  A debugger can help with that.  Ask yourself if it does the same thing every time, and where it is getting "9C" from.

Comment: Consult the [Ralf Brown Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm). If this is a homework, as it appears to be, the correct approach is brushing up the notes and eventually visiting the office hours. :) Your code shows a lack of the basis of the x86 assembly language that I'm sure you don't want to drag all along your studies.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with your last comment Margaret, but I am doing all I can to further my understanding of the material. This is merely one of my many resources that I have at my disposal. As like anything else in life, it's always good to get advice from all angles. You never know who has a trick or two up their sleeves! Thanks for the advice Moby. I am sure that is going to be a vital tool in dealing with this language. It actually goes very in-depth (so long as I've read enough to be able to understand it...working on that bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this definition `message db "Hello, DOS Here!", 0dh, 0ah`, next code will print the complete message:

```
mov  ah, 02h
mov  dl, message     ;Get the H character
int  21h
mov  dl, message+1   ;Get the e character
int  21h
mov  dl, message+2
int  21h
mov  dl, message+3
int  21h
mov  dl, message+4
int  21h
mov  dl, message+5
int  21h
mov  dl, message+6
int  21h
mov  dl, message+7
int  21h
mov  dl, message+8
int  21h
mov  dl, message+9
int  21h
mov  dl, message+10
int  21h
mov  dl, message+11
int  21h
mov  dl, message+12
int  21h
mov  dl, message+13
int  21h
mov  dl, message+14
int  21h
mov  dl, message+15
int  21h
mov  dl, message+16   ;Get the 0Dh carriage return
int  21h
mov  dl, message+17   ;Get the 0Ah linefeed
int  21h
```

Rather stupid, wouldn't you say?
In order to use a loop and obtain much compacter code we need to:

1. Put the address of your message in an address register. You can choose from `SI`, `DI`, `BX` and `BP`. I've picked `BX` in below code.
2. Read one byte at this address.
3. Output the byte with DOS.
4. Increment the pointer in the address register.
5. Repeat steps 2, 3, 4, 5 for all the text by checking if it was the *linefeed character* that you just outputted. Since in your text that's the very last character.

A version of this loop:

```
 mov  bx, OFFSET message  ;1.
Again:
 mov  dl, [bx]            ;2.
 mov  ah, 02h             ;3.
 int  21h
 inc  bx                  ;4.
 cmp  dl, 0Ah             ;5.
 jne  Again
```

---

> I'm also supposed to use push and pop to be able to print the string in the same method but backwards.

To accomplish this next task of yours, you would put a `push dx` in between steps 2. and 3. Then write an additional loop to display the reversed string:

```
Again2:
 pop  dx
 mov  ah, 02h
 int  21h
 cmp  dl, "H"
 jne  Again2
```

The pitfalls here will be that

- you shouldn't output the linefeed and carriage return before the other (real) characters  ==> Hint: do 2 `pop`s before starting the 2nd loop
- you can't readily assume that "H" will only appear as the text's first character  ==> Hint: count the number of `push`s

Comment: Avoid posting full code solutions to homework problems.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I haven't done this in decades and I don't have a compiler in front of me that can do this.  This looks like an assignment so I'm not going to write the code, but I'll point you in the right direction.

[Int 21h function 2](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02) requires you to set `dl` equal to the character you want to output.  No pushes and pops required here since DOS doesn't use the stack for parameter passing.  First, outside of your loop, you want to point a register to the address of the message, something like: `MOV si, message`.  Then, you need to dereference a single byte from the message and put it into `dl`.  This will require using indirect address notation.  Then you can call interrupt 21h and write the character.

As for the loop, there are a few ways to approach it.  You could use a counter, with `cx` being the typical register for that, and use a `LOOP` statement or `DEC` and `JNZ` statements.  Or you could put a marker at the end of the string, and terminate the loop when you hit that marker.  A null character is commonly used for this.  You will also need to move to the next character in the string.  You can do that by adding an index, or by incrementing the value of the `si` register each iteration of the loop.  Something like `INC si`

With all that said, there is a much easier way that avoids the loop but maybe it is cheating.  Take a look at [interrupt 21h function 9](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09)

Comment: Yeah, using function 9 would be 'cheating' as it is one of the other exercises (which was the easy one). I have revised my code and got it to start with the beginning character. I just need to figure out how to get it to move to the next character in the string and not the next character in the ascii table. Here's the revision:

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, using function 9 would be 'cheating' as it is one of the other exercises (which was the easy one). I have revised my code and got it to start with the beginning character. I just need to figure out how to get it to keep looping so that it continues to read the string and not stop arbitrarily. Here's what I've got so far (It prints H and the 15 e's):

```
       .model small
    .data
        message db "Hello, DOS Here!"
    .code
    main proc
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax

        mov ah, 2
        mov cx, 16
        mov dl, message
    L1: 
        int 21h
        mov dl, message + 1
        loop L1

        .EXIT
    main endp
    end main
```

Comment: Learn about indirect addressing.

Comment: Also, by posting this as an answer, you will likely get downvoted.  I recommend posting it as an edit to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Moby. I'm new to posting here so I'll remember that for the future.